# Soft Actor Critic - Losses are not converging

Tags: reinforcement-learning, hyperparameters

I'm trying to implement soft actor-critic algorithm for financial data (stock prices) and I have trouble with losses, no matter what combination of HyperParameters I enter, they are not converging, and basically it caused bad reward return as well. It sounds like the agent is not learning at all.

My question is, would it be related to the data itself (nature of data) or is it something related to the logic of the code?

Comment: I suggest that you ask this question on [Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com/), which is a more appropriate site to ask theoretical questions related to reinforcement learning. If you ask it there, please, delete it from here. Also, provide more details. For example, if you have a plot of the cumulative rewards, that would be helpful. You should describe your data or environment in more detail.

Comment: Thanks,  you are right .. I will do that !